# pass int value from one script to another script in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm trying to pass a `public int score` value from one script to another script but it is giving me the error `an object reference is required to access non-static member` , here it is what I have done

```
public class firearrow : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject Arrow;
    public GameObject apple;
    public int score = 0;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().AddForce (transform.right*1500.0f);

    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Vector3 diff = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
        diff.Normalize();

        float rot_z = Mathf.Atan2(diff.y, diff.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rot_z - 0);

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) {


            GameObject bullet_new;

            bullet_new = Instantiate (Arrow,new Vector2 (-0.23f, -3.78f), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition),Vector2.zero);
            if (hit.collider!= null ) {

                LeanTween.move(bullet_new,  hit.collider.transform.localPosition, 1);
                if(hit.collider.tag == "fruit")
                {           
                    score++;
                    Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject,1);
                    Destroy(bullet_new,1);
                }

            }


        }
    }




}
```

the class I want to access the score

```
public class tick : MonoBehaviour {
    public Text wintext;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        wintext.text = "";
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) {

           if(firearrow.score == 3)
            {
                wintext.text="You Win";

            }


           }

    }
       }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are trying to statically access the variable when it is not set as static. You need to obtain a reference to the "firearrow" script in the tick class instead. Also, your naming conventions are really bad. I would suggest looking up some design patterns and basic tutorials so you understand how things work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change line

```
public int score = 0;
```

to

```
public static int score = 0;
```

Note that you must only have one single instance of class firearrow, otherwise you might run into concurrency issues.

Comment: Thank you so much it helped! and yes I will keep that in mind.